# Could pipeline become transformer?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, nlp, apache-spark-mllib

I need two processes of tokenizing and removing Stop words:

```
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
                  .setInputCol("seg_text")
                  .setOutputCol("raw_words")

val remover = new StopWordsRemover()
                  .setInputCol("raw_words")
                  .setStopWords(stop_words) 
                  .setOutputCol("words")
```

and created pipeline:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
                  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, remover))
```

finally, I wish get the output by this pipeline. I don't know how, or maybe can't.

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline is your ML model that you have to train first, and then it can work for you.

In your case your pipeline contains only preprocessing stages, so finally it will be used before the actual training stage, which could be something like TF-IDF classification for example.

You train it using the `fit` and `transform` methods:

```
val model = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
```

But before that you need to populate `df` with some training documents. You can do it that way:

```
val df = sc.textFile(paths.mkString(",")).toDF("docs")
```

While `path` is a Seq[String] of all your training documents paths.

You can see [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala) of Linear Discriminant Analysis that uses a Pipeline with a StopWordsRemover.

When you're done you will have created a preprocessing ML model. If you need your model to actually do a real processing (like classification, prediction, etc.) then you can just add another algorithm to the pipeline (like TF-IDF), or you can just use it as one algorithm in another pipeline.

After training your model, you probably want to save it, so you can load it later and use it without having to train it again:

```
model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/your-model")
```

And then you can load it like that:

```
val alreadyTrainedModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/your-model")
```